# How to switch from fragment to dialog fragment

Tags: android

I am using a dialog fragment inside a fragment . Now i want to switch from my root fragment to dialog fragment on button click. how is it possible.
Please help me...

dialog fragment code is...

```
  public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MY_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog d = getDialog();

        if (d!=null){
            int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            d.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

on your button click you can use `myDialogFragment.show()`, just posting a code snippet :

```
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();

// You cannot access `getFragmentManager()` directly inside fragment so use getActivity()
myDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "DialogFragment");
```

you should use `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager` depending on which `Fragment` subclass you are using

Answer (score 0):

Write following code in your button click :

```
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();

myDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "myDialogFragment");
```

Comment: make sure you pass right instance of fragmentmanager, it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the `DialogFragment` from another fragment. You could try calling `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

so your code would look like

```
MyDialogFragment mdf = new MyDialogFragment();
mdf.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Comment: Make sure you extend from `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` from support library, instead of `android.app.DialogFragment`